# Is there a library for converting Flash / Flex AS3 TextLayoutFormat data to HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have the job of recreating a flex app in HTML and CSS.  The existing app makes considerable use of TextFlow to layout content.  For several reasons I need to be quite accurate (within a few pixels) with positioning.

The current application is loading data which looks like this:

```
<p paragraphstartindent="0"
  textalign="center"><span alignmentbaseline="useDominantBaseline"
  backgroundalpha="1"
  backgroundcolor="transparent"
  baselineshift="0"
  breakopportunity="auto"
  cffhinting="horizontalStem"
  color="0x0"
  digitcase="default"
  digitwidth="default"
  dominantbaseline="auto"
  fontfamily="ArialCFF"
  fontlookup="embeddedCFF"
  fontsize="22"
  fontstyle="normal"
  fontweight="bold"
  kerning="auto"
  ligaturelevel="common"
  lineheight="120%"
  linethrough="false"
  locale="en"
  renderingmode="cff"
  textalpha="1"
  textdecoration="none"
  textrotation="auto"
  trackingleft="0"
  trackingright="0"
  typographiccase="default">Here is some content which needs to be accurately positioned</span></p>
```

Ideally I'm looking for a library I can use to translate these many attributes into "proper" html and css.  The current technology stack is PHP at the back end and javascript at the front end, but there would be little problem in using any other language to do the translation.

Failing that I guess I'll try and write my own, using [the api reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/TextLayoutFormat.html) as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a lib available for that, but from having a quick look at the docs, it should be too hard to translate over. Most of the options you can ignore as they're impossible to do in css (without going into css3 - I'm assuming you want maximum compatibility here) and the rest are pretty basic (colour, font, padding, line-height...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Wallaby, the Adobe App to convert FLA files to HTML5/CSS can be helpful if you manage to make it work with your Flex Files... http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/

This, of course, would just be a starting point :) but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will never get pixel accuracy in HTML text, by design. Font rendering strategies between browsers, and even different browser modes (eg: IE9, Safari for Windows) can have different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to export your content to HTML with the [TextConverter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with quick and easy since you only need formatted DOM Elements (HTML Tags). This is [part of Flash Player 9] somewhat reliable - you might to give it a try...

```
source         : flashx.textLayout.elements:TextFlow
format         : String
conversionType : String

(returnHTML as Object) = flashx.textLayout.conversion.export(source,format,conversionType)
```